# Vuex: use mutation variable to set a state object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following `vuex` store:

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        myvalue: "test",
        mycount: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        setValue(state, newValue) {
            state.myvalue= newValue;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to tweek the `setValue` mutation a little bit so that I can use the same mutation to change multiple states. I changed my mutation into this:

```
mutations: {
    setValue(state, {item, newValue}) {
        state[item] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Then, in my component I do the following:

```
this.$store.commit('setValue', {'myvalue', 'newtest'});
```

But this doesn't do the trick. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Solution thanks to @thanksd:

`this.$store.commit('setValue', { item: 'myvalue', newValue: 'newtest' })`

Comment: Your new mutation is using [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) for the second parameter, but you're not passing that parameter in correctly. It would need to be `this.$store.commit('setValue', { item: 'myvalue', newValue: 'newtest' })`

Comment: Many thanks. I will add this solution as an edit.